# Nested list without indentation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, margins, enumitem

I'd like to create a nested list inside a text that looks like this text here

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
1. consectetur adipiscing elit
1.1 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
1.1.1 Ut enim ad minim veniam
1.1.1.1 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
```

Currently, I'm using `enumitem`.

I tried setting `leftmargin=0pt`, but this inverts the indent and makes the labels grow towards the left into the margin until the width exceeds the margin and they are eventually cut off.

How can I indent all labels flush with the text?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent \blindtext
\begin{legal}
  \item \blindtext
  \begin{legal}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{legal}
      \item \blindtext
        \begin{legal}
          \item \blindtext
        \end{legal}
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

\end{document}
```

[image: five paragraphs containing lorem ipsum placeholder text, with the last four having labels "1.", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.1" to the left growing into the margins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `wide` key to make the label be part of the list text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*., wide=0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent \blindtext
\begin{legal}
  \item \blindtext
  \begin{legal}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{legal}
      \item \blindtext
        \begin{legal}
          \item \blindtext
        \end{legal}
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want the list items indented, with left aligned labels then you need to create a fixed width for the label to allow it to grow leftwards. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newlength{\maxwidth}
\setlength{\maxwidth}{\widthof{1.1.1.1.1.1.1.}}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.,labelwidth=\maxwidth, align=left,leftmargin=0pt}
\setlist[legal,1]{wide = 0pt,labelwidth = \maxwidth, leftmargin =!, label=\arabic*.}





\begin{document}

\noindent \blindtext
\begin{legal}
  \item \blindtext
  \begin{legal}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{legal}
      \item \blindtext
        \begin{legal}
          \item \blindtext
        \end{legal}
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code]

Comment: Thanks! It also seems the `wide` option alone is already enough. `\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*., wide=0pt}`

Comment: @mdcq Thanks. You're right. The other parameters were left over from my testing. I've updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Also, is there a way to preserve the indentation of the following lines to start where the text in the first line starts like in the original image?

Comment: @mdcq I've added a possible solution to your comment question.

Comment: Thanks! It seems `\setlist[legal,1]` only needs to include options not already set by the `\setlist[legal]` command, e.g. `\setlist[legal,1]{leftmargin=!}`